# how to create custom design for chart to plot data in android

Tags: android, charts

I have to plot data into two types of cjart (line and bar). Chart require custom design and zooming,sliding,data export option. How can I manage all these things?  I mean what is the best 3rd party library for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using  [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). and it's pretty good. I recommend it to you.